# MS Access 2010: How to Export All Make-Table Query Fields to Excel

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'd like to export All of my queries from MS Access to Excel. I currently am able to export all non-make-table queries, however, I don't see the Make-Table queries popping up. Is there any way to **export the Make-Table Queries** in a similar fashion? Thanks.

```
Sub ListQueriesAndFields()
 'Macro Purpose:  Write all Query and field names to and Excel file
 'Source:  vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=707
 'Updates by Derek - Added column headers, modified base setting for loop to include all fields,
 '                   added type, size, and description properties to export
 'Updates by Alex - Converted to be used for Queries instead of Tables.

Dim lTbl As Long
Dim lFld As Long
Dim dBase As Database
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim wbExcel As Object
Dim lRow As Long

 'Set current database to a variable and create a new Excel instance
Set dBase = CurrentDb
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wbExcel = xlApp.workbooks.Add

 'Set on error in case there are no tables
On Error Resume Next

'DJK 2011/01/27 - Added in column headers below
lRow = 1
With wbExcel.sheets(1)
    .Range("A" & lRow) = "Table Name"
    .Range("B" & lRow) = "Field Name"
    .Range("C" & lRow) = "Type"
    .Range("D" & lRow) = "Size"
    .Range("E" & lRow) = "Description"
End With


'AMK - Converted 5/2/2016 for use with Queries instead of Tables
For lQry = 0 To dBase.QueryDefs.Count
     'If the table name is a temporary or system table then ignore it
    If Left(dBase.QueryDefs(lQry).Name, 1) = "~" Or _
    Left(dBase.QueryDefs(lQry).Name, 4) = "MSYS" Then
         '~ indicates a temporary table
         'MSYS indicates a system level table
    Else
         'Otherwise, loop through each query, writing the query and field names
         'to the Excel file
        For lFld = 0 To dBase.QueryDefs(lQry).Fields.Count - 1  'DJK 2011/01/27 - Changed initial base from 1 to 0, and added type, size, and description
            lRow = lRow + 1
            With wbExcel.sheets(1)
                .Range("A" & lRow) = dBase.QueryDefs(lQry).Name
                .Range("B" & lRow) = dBase.QueryDefs(lQry).Fields(lFld).Name
                .Range("C" & lRow) = dBase.QueryDefs(lQry).Fields(lFld).Type
                .Range("D" & lRow) = dBase.QueryDefs(lQry).Fields(lFld).Size
                .Range("E" & lRow) = dBase.QueryDefs(lQry).Fields(lFld).Properties("Description")
            End With
        Next lFld
    End If
Next lQry
 'Resume error breaks
On Error GoTo 0

 'Set Excel to visible and release it from memory
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set wbExcel = Nothing

 'Release database object from memory
Set dBase = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: What you have should work. I have an export routine that works exactly as yours (on the QueryDef part) and it also extracts the querys with `Type = dbQMakeTable`. Note: your first For should go to `Count -1`.

Comment: @HansUp, a Make Table Query uses SQL `CREATE` and is not necessarilly a `SELECT INTO`.

Comment: My work-around was to take the actual table that gets created (and thus exists in my VBA output that I ran on the tables (very similar to the code above, just for Tables). But then I have to still match the make-table table names back to their query names. My end result has to be All Query Names + their field names.

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work. I have an export routine that works exactly as yours (on the QueryDef part) and it also extracts the querys with `Type = dbQMakeTable`.

However, a Make Table Query may not have field names, so your second For loop will not produce any results making you think it didn't work.

Use your debugger to check you get the Make Table Queries and then check the fields. Maybe these queries only have `SQL` set to make the table. You can then analyze the SQL. It looks like `CREATE TABLE <name> (<fields...>);`

Comment: For a saved `CREATE TABLE` query, the `QueryDef.Type` property is `dbQDDL` (96), not `dbQMakeTable` (80).

Comment: Hmm, so the Make Table Query may not have any fields, but just be defined as a saved SQL statement? Like a view in MySQL?